# Truncate and add form elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, truncate

I am a newbie in jquery and was trying to truncate form element strings and then concatenate or add them later.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var sur = $('#field_surname').val(); //Get value from field surname and store it in sur
var name = $('#field_adult_name').val(); //Get value from field adult_name and store it in name
var pcode = $('#field_postcode').val();// Get value from field postcode and store it in pcode
var surshort = jQuery.trim(sur).substring(0, 3); //truncate first three letters
var nameshort = jQuery.trim(name).substring(0, 3);//truncate first three letters
var pcodeshort = jQuery.trim(pcode).substring(0, 12);//truncate first 12 letters
var msg = surshort+nameshort+pcodeshort; // Add all the strings
$( "#field_sur" ).val("SKU"+msg);  // write values in field_sur and prefix SKU to it
});
```

Most of the queries I have seen refer to doing those after submission or on submit or form validate event, however I want it when the user fills in the data

Therefore I also tried using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  /*Fire up the script when the below three fields change*/
  $('#field_surname', '#field_adult_name','#field_postcode' ).change(function(){
    var sur = $('#field_surname').val();
    var name = $('#field_adult_name').val();
    var pcode = $('#field_postcode').val();
    var surshort = jQuery.trim(sur).substring(0, 3);
    var nameshort = jQuery.trim(name).substring(0, 3);
    var pcodeshort = jQuery.trim(pcode).substring(0, 12);
    var msg = surshort+nameshort+pcodeshort;
    $('#field_sur').val("SKU"+msg);  
   });

});
```

But after several hours, I am unable to get the desired value in #sur_field. I am using latest wordpress with Zia3 custom css and js plugin to inject js. Please assist.

Comment: your code looks fine, is your html correct? What does your console say?

Comment: @David: The console is blank. Apparently no value is calculated. I am unsure where I am going wrong.

Comment: use console log to write to the console. The code is correct but obviously we can't see 1. that the code is output on the page 2. that you have the correct html fields, etc!

Comment: @David: When I write below code I get result for one function, I am not sure how to track changes on three seperate change instances. 
'$('#field_surname').change(function(){
    var sur = $('#field_surname').val();
    var name = $('#field_adult_name').val();
    var pcode = $('#field_postcode').val();
    var surshort = jQuery.trim(sur).substring(0, 3);
    var nameshort = jQuery.trim(name).substring(0, 3);
    var pcodeshort = jQuery.trim(pcode).substring(0, 12);
    var msg = surshort+nameshort+pcodeshort;
    $('#field_sur').val("MEM"+msg);  
   });'

Comment: `console.log(sur);` for a start....input after the line of code that gets the value, see what i mean? also do `console.log('test');` to ensure your function actually fires. you will get a ordered list of output to the console. There's not much point in putting code in comments, its very unreadable! `console.log()` is a function you should be using a lot to debug your js, there are a lot of things that go wrong with js that stop the script. PS you are looking on chrome/ firefox console?

Comment: @David: Thanks for the input. I tried it. Here is the output.
console.log(sur)
VM24745:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: sur is not defined

Comment: you need to put it after you define sur...at least you know your code is running. Play around with it to find what is and isn't being defined. start with msg just before you write the value to the field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David for enlightening me with console.log troubleshooting.

However, I found the problem and in the meantime an alternative solution to my problem.

The problem was:
`$('#field_surname', '#field_adult_name','#field_postcode' ).change(function(){`

and one has to not declare each div ids instead declare it all in one go like this:
`$('#field_surname, #field_adult_name, #field_postcode').change(function(){`

The alternative is to use seperate functions and call them in another variable but it would again require tracking changes of three form elements at once using above method which is lenghty but neat:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#field_surname').change(function(){
      var sur = $('#field_surname').val();
      var surshort = jQuery.trim(sur).substring(0, 3);
      $('#field_sur').val("MEM"+surshort);
    });
    $('#field_adult_name').change(function(){                             
      var name = $('#field_adult_name').val();
      var nameshort = jQuery.trim(name).substring(0, 3);
      $('#field_shortname').val(nameshort);
    });
    $('#field_postcode').change(function(){
      var pcode = $('#field_postcode').val();
      var pcodeshort = jQuery.trim(pcode).substring(0, 12);
      $('#field_shortpcode').val(pcodeshort);
    });
    $('#field_sur, #field_shortname, #field_shortpcode').blur(function(){
      var val1 = $("#field_sur").val();
      var val2 = $("#field_shortname").val();
      var val3 = $("#field_shortpcode").val();
      $("#field_msg").val(val1+val2+val3);
    });

});
```

Hope it helps to the newbie jquery users like me :)